# How to restrict access to application features based on plan

Tags: nestjs, access-control

I'm currently developing a application in nestjs that provides some service to the user. User will select a plan,features will be accessible based on the limit set by plan.

As an **example**: say there are 3 **plan**, and 4 **features**

- User with **plan A** has access to feature a,b.
- User with **plan B** has access to feature a,b,c.
- User with **plan C** has access to feature a,b,c,d.

So I am looking for the best way to get this implementation done, and main concern is

- **maintainability/changeability**:- Should be able to add more plan and features to the plan.
- efficiency: Better and efficient code.

I have never implemented this before, so I have no clue about how to implement above feature. Any tips/resources/examples? I have read about RBAC and ACL.

Thanks in advance

Comment: A similar question was asked at stack exchange https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/121188/how-to-implement-restricted-access-to-application-features